# Internationalization of RPM spec

Tags: internationalization, rpm

A single rpm spec file has to support multiple locale of Linux [EN & JA]. 
Suppose it checks Java is existing, if not throws exception, "*Error: Java not installed*". On Japanese machine the Japanese message should be shown. In the spec file java_err_msg is declared as macro. I want to know how to localize below '**java_err_msg**' to behave as Summary, Group, Description, etc.

**%define java_err_msg "*Error: Java not installed*"**

So, that spec file picks corresponding message based on locale of PC.
I am looking for solution like in the Summary, Group, description case where based on system locale rpm will display the appropriate message. As below;
*Summary: AppName

Summary(ja):  AppName[in Japanese]

Group: XYZ Group

Group(ja): XYZ Group[in Japanese]*

Please let me know for any better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are testing for java existence in an rpm %pre script let.

If you have only a single message in 2 locales, then you can
test the LC_ALL envvar and hardcode both the EN and JA messages emitting
as appropriate.

Slightly better is to write a program with proper locale handling
that is invoked in the %pre script, and emits a localized message
to stderr as appropriate.

There are no means to include an i18n error message in an rpm header
from a rpm.spec file: the only i18n tags are Summary:, Group:, and %description.

I'm not sure how to throw an exception if java does not exist. RPM is
a C, not a C++, program, and there are no exceptions in C.